# MySQL is not using composite index with ORDER BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, query-optimization, database-performance, database-indexes

I have a table `user` that looks like this

```
id | first_name | last_name | org_id
```

This table has few million entries.

I want to run the below query with an exact match and an order by clause

```
     select * from user 
     where org_id = "some id" 
     ORDER BY first_name asc, last_name asc 
     limit 100;
```

I also have the following indexes:

- org_id
- org_id, first_name, last_name

When I run an explain on this query, mysql uses `org_id` index instead of the composite index on `org_id, first_name, last_name`.

This is the output of the explain query

[image: explain result of the above query]

I can see in the `possible keys` sections where mysql evaluates the composite index but still does not uses it.

I have read several answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/725439/2168941) one which says that composite index should be used here.

This query is really slow in case the match is really. Any idea

- why mysql is not using the composite index?
- How can I speed up this query?

Edit 1: Here is the table DDL

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `organisation_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `organisation_id` (`organisation_id`,`email`),
  KEY `idx_first_name_last_name` (`first_name`(32),`last_name`(32)),
  KEY `idx_organisation_id_first_name_last_name` (`organisation_id`,`first_name`(32),`last_name`(32)),
  CONSTRAINT `user_org_fkey` FOREIGN KEY (`organisation_id`) REFERENCES `organisation` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

TIA

Update: Updating the index as mentioned by Liki solved the issue for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd think that optimizer would select the composite index as you expected. (But  it's not in your database)

I tested the same situation on my test DB, but it selects the composite index.

Fortunately, there is an index hint in MySQL for optimizer decisions.

```
tbl_name [[AS] alias] [index_hint_list]

index_hint_list:
    index_hint [index_hint] ...

index_hint:
    USE {INDEX|KEY}
      [FOR {JOIN|ORDER BY|GROUP BY}] ([index_list])
  | {IGNORE|FORCE} {INDEX|KEY}
      [FOR {JOIN|ORDER BY|GROUP BY}] (index_list)

index_list:
    index_name [, index_name] ...
```

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 USE INDEX (col1_index,col2_index)
  WHERE col1=1 AND col2=2 AND col3=3;

SELECT * FROM table1 IGNORE INDEX (col3_index)
  WHERE col1=1 AND col2=2 AND col3=3;
```

**Finally, could you try to run your SQL with the following hint?**

```
select
  *
from
  `user` USE INDEX (your_composit_index_name)
where org_id = "some id"
ORDER BY first_name asc,
  last_name asc
limit 100;
```

**Edit 1: Index fix**

Please fix your index.  Your key `lengths` are defined as 32 in index `idx_first_name_last_name`, but they should be 255 lengths.

```
ALTER TABLE `user` DROP INDEX `idx_first_name_last_name`, ADD KEY `idx_first_name_last_name` (`first_name`, `last_name`);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Liki. When I run explain with `USE INDEX`, the `rows` in the `EXPLAIN` query has jumped from 44K to 59K. This does not make sense to me as the where condition remains the same. 

Any idea what that would be the case?

Comment: @AbhinavD could you give me the full DDL of your table and SQL? It's weird.

Comment: @AbhinavD And let me know MySQL version as well

Comment: updated in the question

Comment: `explain select * from user use index for ORDER BY (idx_organisation_id_first_name_last_name)
     where organisation_id = "some id" 
     ORDER BY first_name asc, last_name asc 
     limit 100;` How about this? Could you let me know the result?

Comment: And could you try to run this query `SELECT first_name, last_name FROM USER USE INDEX (idx_organisation_id_first_name_last_name)
     WHERE organisation_id = "some id" 
     ORDER BY first_name ASC, last_name ASC 
     LIMIT 100;    `?

Comment: @AbhinavD I updated my answer. There is a mistake in your index definition. After fixing it, please try to run `SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM USER 
 USE INDEX for order by(idx_first_name_last_name)
WHERE organisation_id = "some id" 
ORDER BY first_name ASC, last_name ASC 
LIMIT 100;     `

Comment: Thanks a lot @Liki. I will make the changes and update here

Answer (score 1):

`DROP` your `INDEX(org_id)`, it may be getting in the way of using the better `INDEX(org_id, first, last)`.  If that helps, it will add more evidence of this gross optimization flaw.

Comment: This is very interesting as I can now drop the single index. 

When I run explain with `USE INDEX`, the rows in the `EXPLAIN` query has jumped from 44K to 59K. This does not make sense to me as the where condition remains the same. Any idea what that would be the case?

Comment: The "Row" count in Explain is just an estimate.  Altering the table changes the statistics that it used for estimating.  44->59 is not significant.